# Do I need a database to have an online leaderboard

Tags: database, web

I'm trying to make a website for a school activity and I want to display a leaderboard with various different stats in a table. I have managed the HTML/CSS parts but for the data itself, I'm not sure if I'm going to need to use a database. The final goal is to be able to have a "log-in" page in the website itself (using a hidden button) to be able to modify values from the website itself. Could this be achieved without a database or would I need one? If so, what are some good resources to look at to get all the backend working?

I haven't tried to use a backend. I'm confident I can implement the functionality in Javascript but am not sure if once ported to the server for the website it'll work the same

Comment: you can use plain files instead of the DB, but then you need to deal with things like locking.

Comment: How long do you expect the leaderboard to be, and how often will it be updated? If it doesn't have to be up-to-the-moment live, you can get away with generating it periodically. You can use a service for storage, and a service for generating the leaderboard.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *data persistence method*, of which a database is a good example. It's not the only one:

- Plain files
- File-based "embedded" databases like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)
- Services like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)

Your site will be just static pages until you have some kind of persistence method.

This is where your choice of method will in part dictate your choice of *back-end*, that is the server-side part of the persistence. In most cases you can use Python, Ruby, Node.js, PHP or whatever you see fit so long as it can handle HTTP type requests.

You mentioned JavaScript, so Node might be a good choice, though you'll need to pick a *framework* to build off of.

You can also go "serverless" as in use services like Firebase which can hook in via client-side JavaScript and network calls.